# MySQL Update table based on same table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having the issue 'you can't specify target table for update in from clause". I know what it means and I've found some solutions but my syntax is just not working, so I'm asking for help. The query I want to run is

```
("UPDATE people SET isAlive = '1' WHERE family = (SELECT family FROM people WHERE person = :person)")
```

I've tried using people AS a and the second people AS b but I'm just stumped at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by joining that table back on itself:

```
UPDATE people p1 
join people p2 on p1.family=p2.family 
SET p1.isAlive = '1' 
where p2.person= :person
```